# extract the ajax response in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i extract the returned response of the ajax response? to catch the response i should write:

```
$.post('server.php',{x : 9}, function(response){
    alert(response);
});
```

Now, how can i take the " response " out of the function(){} ?, because it doesn't exist outside .. and i wanna compare it with some other value, i attempted to assign it to a global var and to a jQuery object " $response ", but it always "undefined" while the " response " it self have the correct value !.. 
Generally  i want it this way, if possible :)

```
response= $.post('..',{.. : ..});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Am i understanding you right? You already did `var serverresponse;` outside of the post and did `serverresponse = response` in the post?

Comment: As I understand, he wants to send an XHR-request and have the response converted to valid JScript object/variable so that he could use the value elsewhere...

Comment: @dksan yes i did but always return undefined !

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Just as you can't do:

```
var foo = jQuery('button').click(somefunction);
```

… and expect to get the return value in foo.

Ajax just sets up some code to run **when** the HTTP response arrives from the server.

You need to design your code so that the callback function can do what you want to do with the data.

Answer (score 1):

What are wanting to do ain't going to happen since the ajax call is not synchronous. Solution, put whatever logic you need with the response in the callback function and use closure variables for context.

Comment: "ajax call is not synchronous", yes that's it !!, what shall i do now :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the comparison in the callback method. Using the new and shiny [Deffered object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) introduced in jQuery 1.5 you can do this in a nice readable manner:

```
$.when(postToServer())
    .then(function(response){
        // Logic to compare response
    });

function postToServer(){
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $.post('server.php', {x : 9}, dfd.resolve);
    return dfd.promise();
};
```

Comment: Is there a difference between the code in the `then` callback and the code in the success callback in the OP's question? Seems to me it would be the same issue.

Comment: The 'then' callback is called when the Deffered is resolved in all functions called by 'when'. Indeed this does not solve the problem but ,as I said, IMHO makes the code more readable.

Answer (score -2):

Usually it goes this way, if your `dataType = "json"`:

```
function myFunc ()
{
    var jqHXR = jQuery.ajax({
        async : false,
        dataType : "json"
    });

    return jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
}
```

Returns the parsed value as a valid Jscript object. Make sure its Synchronous XHR call though, by providing { 'async' : false } parameter to jQuery.ajax(); as shown above.

Comment: Please provide reason as well, when you downvote the answer... Thx!

Comment: I'm guessing people downvote because your answer doesn't have anything to do with the question.

Comment: @Niklas : Doesn't OP want to retrieve the value of his XHR request as a valid JS object/variable so that he could use it elsewhere in upper scope? jQuery.post() is just another wrapper function for jQuery.ajax(), so what's it that I am missing?

Comment: No, he wants access to the variable `response`, which is already a perfectly valid JS object of some sort, in the scope where he's performing the `.post`. This won't work, which other answer's have clarified. JSON has not been mentioned. Also, your code is broken in exactly the same way the OP's is. It won't work.

Comment: @Niklas : Dear Niklos, my code is working perfectly in a large scale project [content management system] without any problems. You are right, he didn't mention JSON, but he clearly mentioned that he wants the response object in his last piece of code : `response= $.post('..',{.. : ..});`. I just gave option in case if he is dealing with JSON objects. The only downside would be if he is dealing with way LARGE data, in which case, Async XHR call might have his browser locked, which is undesirable effect of course.

Comment: Oh, I see. You're very consistently confusing asynchronous and synchronous. Now it all makes sense :).

Comment: @Niklos : Oh my... I am sorry, lol :) Yea, its sync, not async - let me fix the code :) Thx a lot.

Comment: It's still not very helpful, with the assumption about dataType. Also, if you're letting jQuery handle the deserialization, what's the point with .parseJSON on .responseText? Now that you've made it a synchronous call, what's up with the success callback? I'm only trying to explain why you're receiving downvotes, by the way.

Comment: No, you don't need success callback there, ok, lets remove that one too :) Re unserialization: jqXHR variable is jQuery object, not the value of XHR response - you need to fetch the `responseText` property and unserialize it to get your working response.

Comment: I stand corrected on that point. I have never dealt with synchronous calls using jQuery, as I learnt to avoid synchronous XHRs long before jQuery was released :).

Comment: But in those old good days, computers and Internet were much slower... Don't you think Sync-XHRs aren't that dangerous/undesirable anymore? Plus, how are we supposed to get XHR's response/value as a JS variable [as we see here in this example]?

Comment: Oh, that's too much for me to handle, people just tell me a way or another to do it .. i am using it in a form .. > onsubmit > ajax " check some user value if exists " > if exists .. stop, else do the submission !.. How to do it, it can't be that hard to do ... Thanks very much for your time :)

Comment: Where is the form? Show it to us and MAYBE someone will come up with something more concrete and substantial.